# How to unit test and refactor this PHP function?

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

**Disclaimer**: yes, I have read the FAQ and think such a question in inside the boundaries of Stackoverflow. No, I do not know how to properly name it. :(

My question is simple: how to ***unit*** test the following method and what refactoring should I do to make it testable? I repeat: I do not want to require the DB and Yii application instance floating around to test this function.

```
public function getOrderCountGroupedByStatus()
{
    $arr = $this->db->createCommand()
        ->select('COUNT( status ) AS count_status, status')
        ->from('order_item')
        ->group('status')
        ->order('status')
        ->queryAll();

    $orderItemsCountByStatus = array();
    foreach($arr as $os)
        $orderItemsCountByStatus[(int)$os['status']] = $os['count_status'];

    return $orderItemsCountByStatus;
}
```

This is legacy code checked for validity by manual testing the whole application.

It's from PHP application based on [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com).

`$this->db` is a [CDbConnection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection) object. `$this->db->createCommand()` returns a [CDbCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand) object.

`CDbCommand.queryAll()` returns the iterable object which emits an array `array('status' => (string), 'count_status' => (int))` on each iteration.

There are clearly two responsibilities in this method: first one fetches raw data from the external data source, second one rearranges the raw data to final results. I understand that it should be separated somehow.

1. Interface to the database uses factory method which returns an object with chainable methods. This is a nightmare to mock. I started to write a manual fake for both CDbCommand and a CDbConnection which creates it, but I have already written so much code that it probably require it's own unit tests. I don't understand at all how I should mock the requests to the database.
2. This code is just a single example. I have a lot of similar methods, but many of them call the database not once, but several times, so the "get raw data, reformat it" is probably not a pattern here, but I am not sure about it.

Lastly: what I am testing here is described by the name of relevant PHPUnit test method:

```
public function CanFindNumberOfOrdersGroupedByStatus()
```

Main reason why I am stuck here is that what I test is basically *whether the SUT can successfully get some stats from the persistence storage*, that's all. All the interaction with the DB are implementation details here, but in the legacy codebase I am working with it's the only means to connect to persistence storage (using the CDbCommand/CDbConnection combo above) and this persistence storage is a MySQL database.

I wonder whether I need to implement the complete backend for CDbConnection which will work with in-memory fixtures instead of real DB to properly unit-test such methods.

And yes, preventing possible questions, usage of ActiveRecords built-in in Yii framework is prohibited by project politics.

Comment: Set up a separate test DB and simply test for known results?

Comment: @IvoRenkema Man, I am talking about `unit` tests here. The whole issue is to **not** use the real DB at all, otherwise everyone knows how to test such a function.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to write much code to test this at all. Yii has an excellent testing framework including DB testing and DB fixture capabilities that will perfectly cover this legacy function.

For your reading:

[Testing in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.overview) (see also sections on fixtures therein)

Generally what you will end up doing is:

1. Set up test config and test bootstrap file as prescribed in the guide (default example app will contain a sample test config/bootstrap setup).
2. Create test DB with schema and point your test config at that.
3. Write a class that extends [CDbTestCase](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbTestCase). This is just your ordinary PHPUnit test with Yii's special additions that make testing with DB fixtures easier. If you are not familiar with PHPUnit, see [the docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) for that.
4. Write some fixtures for your test DB according to the Yii guide. This ensures test data for your test DB.
5. Write tests that call your Order class's function "as is" and assert results just like in ordinary unit tests, e.g. (this code inside your unit test CDbTestCase subclass):

   $this->assertEquals(
     array(1 => 2, 2 => 5),
     Order::model()->getOrderCountGroupedByStatus()
   );

Comment: I have answered to one commenter, answer the same to you: I neither need nor want to raise the whole MySQL instance and instantiate the Yii application just to test this function. I want **unit** tests, not integration ones. Thank you, I know perfectly how to setup DB testing with Yii, been there, done that.